# Modify part of list using set?

Tags: scheme, racket

Using `set!` I want to be able to modify a local state `list` variable `lst`, but only a part of it

For example, I want to insert values inside an inner list:

```
((1 2) (4 5))
```

becomes

```
((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

I want to be able to do something like `set! (car lst) (append (car lst) 3)`

But that seems to only modify the temporary variable generated by `(car lst)`.

The only way I can think of is to create a new list with the new desired values and set `lst` to be the new list, but that seems wasteful and unnecessary. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: are they all lists? or cons? i mean, is it defined this way: (define lst (list (list 1 2) (list 4 5))) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
(define lst (list (list 1 2) (list 4 5)))
lst
> ((1 2) (4 5))
(set-cdr! (cdar lst) (list 3))
lst
> ((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

when modifying cons/lists you should use set-cdr! and set-car!

EDIT: for racket

use mutable list:

```
(require racket/mpair)
(define lst (mlist (mlist 1 2) (mlist 4 5)))
lst
> (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2 '())) (mcons (mcons 4 (mcons 5 '())) '()))
(set-mcdr! (mcdr (mcar lst)) (list 3))
> (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2 #<promise:temp2>)) (mcons (mcons 4 (mcons 5 '())) '()))
lst
```

Comment: Sorry I'm using racket (should've been clearer) and it doesn't have set-car!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which interpreter of Scheme you're using, you might need to do a bit more of work. For instance, in Racket the list primitives are *not* mutable by default, and you'll have to use the mutable version of the procedures:

```
(require scheme/mpair)
(define lst (mlist (mlist 1 2) (mlist 4 5)))
lst
(set-mcdr! (mcdr (mcar lst)) (mlist 3))
lst
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard idiom in Scheme for creating a list piecemeal is to prepend elements to the front, using `cons`, and not trying to `set-cdr!` the last cons cell in the list. At the end, when your list is done, you can then use `reverse` to get the elements in the correct order. This way, no list mutation is necessary per se.

So if you're trying to create the list `(1 2 3)` piecemeal:

- Start off with the empty list, `()`, and `cons` 1 to it. This gives you `(1)`.
- Then `cons` 2 to the list: `(2 1)`
- Then `cons` 3 to the list: `(3 2 1)`
- Finally, when you're done building the list, reverse it: `(1 2 3)`

You may ask why this is "better". That's because accessing the last pair to `set-cdr!` is an O(n) operation; with linked lists, elements are not random-access, but are linear on the element position being accessed. Whereas, `cons` is always O(1).

`reverse` is an O(n) operation, but as long as you're doing it only at the end (when you are ready to build the list in the correct order), rather than calling it all the time, that won't detrimentally affect performance.

Comment: yes but this is about set!, not how to create a list. I want to modify a local state variable.